# ios swift parse: Saving to keychain and print out data from keychain and do a login

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, keychain

I implemented this code https://github.com/exchangegroup/keychain-swift to make use of the keychain. My question as a bloody beginner:

I use parse.com as API.
I would like to save username, password and nickname to the keychain in order to login the user automatically. What works right now quite well, but when I try to print out the nickname with

```
let KeyChainNickname = "LocalNickname"
let currentNickname = TegKeychain.get(KeyChainNickname)
self.helloUserLabel.text = "Welcome \(currentNickname)"
```

I get this: Welcome Optional("MyNickname") which is the right nickname but surrounded by  Optional("")

How can I print out the name without that Optional("")?

As I use parse.com I could also just pin the user data, where is really the difference between Parse local data store and the keychain? Beside the fact, that the keychain can by synced to other ios devices? Thats why I would prefer the keychain method.

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this `!` in your code like this:

```
let currentNickname = TegKeychain.get(KeyChainNickname)!
self.helloUserLabel.text = "Welcome \(currentNickname)"
```

But you can use this `!` if you are sure that currentNickname will defiantly get a value.

And your output will be `"MyNickname"`.

**EDIT:**

```
if let currentNickname = TegKeychain.get(KeyChainNickname){

self.helloUserLabel.text = "Welcome \(currentNickname)"
}
```

You can try this too.

Comment: Hmm... Problem is that in the case you open the app first time, this value is empty and will produce a crash... Is there any other way around this? Sorry - I could have seen this before...

Comment: You can use `if` condition for it.

Comment: I have updated the code, let me know if you face any problem with it.

Comment: Yes, it helped me for my understanding! But I decided to leave the nickname out of keychain, as I can get the data anyways from the login to parse through the PFUser. But thanks a lot for your help!!